# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments // Swift

Tags: swift

I am currently working on a program for a school assignment that focuses on classes and subclasses.

In this program, there is a religious Christian (the main class) who has two sub-classes (Baptist and Presbyterian) attached to that main class. My problem is that I am trying to follow the instructions and create the people who align themselves with the sub-classes, but I am getting an error that states:

> argument passed to call that takes no arguments

I am wondering how to fix this.

Error occurs on this line:

```
var Mary: Presbyterian = Christian(modeOfBaptism: "Sprinkling")
```

My Code:

```
import UIKit

/*
 Create a base class called Christian and initialize it with Boolean variables indicating at least two shared Christian beliefs such as the Trinity and the inspiration of Scripture and set their default values to true. Create an empty baptism method. Create a person called Peter who is a Christian. If you have assigned the default values correctly, simply assigning the class to Peter will attribute those beliefs without having to specify them at initialization time.

 Use the playground to call and display Peter's beliefs in the right column (i.e. display it without printing it to the console). */

class Christian {
    var trinity: Bool = true
    var inspirationOfScripture: Bool = true

    func baptism() {

    }
}

var peter = Christian() //<- Do I need anything else inside the parentheses?
peter.trinity

 /*Create two Christian subclasses for Baptist and Presbyterian believers and set a default string value for mode of baptism and set its default to immersion and sprinkling respectively.*/

class Baptist: Christian {
    var modeOfBaptism: String = "Immersion"
    var ageOfAccountability: Bool

    init (ageOfAccountability: Bool) {
        self.ageOfAccountability = true
    }

    override func baptism() {
        if modeOfBaptism == "Immersion".lowercased() && ageOfAccountability == true {
            print ("You will be baptized by Immersion")
        } else {
            print ("Not yet. Ask me about this later.")
        }
    }

}

class Presbyterian: Christian {
    var modeOfBaptism: String = "Sprinkling"

    override func baptism() {
        if modeOfBaptism == "Sprinkling".lowercased() {
            print ("You will be baptized by Sprinkling")
        } else {
            print ("You will not be baptized by Sprinkling")
        }
    }
}

 /*Create an age of accountability variable for the Baptist class and set up an initializer that defaults to true. This means that if we instantiate a new Baptist, he or she will inherit Christian beliefs on the Trinity, mode of baptism and will be assumed to be of the age of accountability without having do implement memberwise initialization. With an initializer for age of accountability, you can do memberwise initialization of that single variable at instantiation time.

 Override the baptism method for each denomination class that the method prints how a person would be baptized (immersion/sprinkling). In the Baptist class, create an if/else test that will only baptize if the person's age of accountability is true. If not, print something like, "Not yet. Ask me about this later."*/

 /*Create a Baptist called Billy and a Presbyterian called John. You should be able to instantiate them by using the default initial values. Display their beliefs on the Trinity (should be the same) and mode of baptism (should be different).*/

var Billy: Baptist = Baptist(ageOfAccountability: true)
Billy.trinity
Billy.modeOfBaptism

var John: Presbyterian = Presbyterian()
John.trinity
John.modeOfBaptism

 /*Baptize Billy so that when we call the method we see a sentence in the console that says something like, "You have been immersed."*/

 Christian.baptism(Billy)

 /*Create a child of Billy called Suzie and use the initializer to specify that her age of accountability is false. Try to baptize Suzie.*/

var Suzie: Baptist = Baptist(ageOfAccountability: false)
Baptist.baptism(Suzie)

 /*Make a new Presbyterian believer and call her Mary. Display Mary's belief about the mode of baptism in the right-hand column.*/

var Mary: Presbyterian = Christian(modeOfBaptism: "Sprinkling")
Mary.modeOfBaptism

 /*Now imagine that Mary joins a Reformed Baptist church (kind of a hybrid Baptist and Presbyterian church) and changes her beliefs to support immersion. Change Mary's baptism belief and display what she believes about the mode of baptism now.
 */

Mary.modeOfBaptism = "Immersion"
```

Comment: You should tell us the exact line(s) that this error occurs on

Comment: It is customary to make the names of **type** (classes, structs, enums and protocols) Capitalized, and names of variables, instances and values lowercase. The practice is so widespread that by nort adhering to it, your code becomes very unreadable :)

Comment: @JakeG I have updated the post. My bad for not stating that from the start

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thank you for the advice. I forgot about that practice. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit  
class Christian {
    var trinity: Bool = true
    var inspirationOfScripture: Bool = true

    func baptism() {

    }
}

var peter = Christian()
peter.trinity

class Baptist: Christian {
    var modeOfBaptism: String = "Immersion"
    var ageOfAccountability: Bool

    init (ageOfAccountability: Bool) {
        self.ageOfAccountability = true
    }

    override func baptism() {
        if modeOfBaptism == "Immersion".lowercased() && ageOfAccountability == true {
            print ("You will be baptized by Immersion")
        } else {
            print ("Not yet. Ask me about this later.")
        }
    }

}

class Presbyterian: Christian {
    var modeOfBaptism: String = "Sprinkling"

    override func baptism() {
        if modeOfBaptism == "Sprinkling".lowercased() {
            print ("You will be baptized by Sprinkling")
        } else {
            print ("You will not be baptized by Sprinkling")
        }
    }
}

var Billy: Baptist = Baptist(ageOfAccountability: true)
Billy.trinity
Billy.modeOfBaptism

var John: Presbyterian = Presbyterian()
John.trinity
John.modeOfBaptism

Billy.baptism()

var Suzie: Baptist = Baptist(ageOfAccountability: false)
Suzie.baptism()

var Mary: Christian = Presbyterian()
Mary.baptism()

 /*Now imagine that Mary joins a Reformed Baptist church (kind of a hybrid Baptist and Presbyterian church) and changes her beliefs to support immersion. Change Mary's baptism belief and display what she believes about the mode of baptism now.
 */

Mary = Baptist(ageOfAccountability: true)
Mary.baptism()
```

I have re-written your code for you and it should work fine now

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with lines such as `Christian.baptism(Billy)`

You have created an object, `billy` of class `Christian`. Your function `baptism()` takes no arguments, by your design. (Otherwise it would be `func baptism(arg1: Type1)`.

Instead of calling `Christian.baptism(Billy)`, you should be calling `billy.baptism()`.

As another user has pointed out, you should really capitalize your classes, such as `Christian` and `Presbyterian`, but the *instances* of these objects, `billy` and `john` should be lowercase to follow standard object oriented coding practices.

**Edit**: After reading your update, it is clear you have several areas of issue.

`var Mary: Presbyterian = Christian(modeOfBaptism: "Sprinkling")` is causing an error, because your constructor for Christian does not have an initializer that takes an argument `modeOfBaptism`.

You also are trying to set a `Christian` to a `Presbyterian`. Remember, based on your subclassing, a `Presbyterian` is a `Christian` but a `Christian` cannot be forced to a `Presbyterian` object because a `Christian` is not necessarily a `Presbyterian`.

May I suggest reading through an [In-Depth Guide to Initialization](https://www.raywenderlich.com/119922/swift-tutorial-initialization-part-1) as these are some pretty fundamental concepts you should fully understand before further development.

Comment: Thank You. Would this all be fixed by adding _var modeOfBaptism: String = ""_ in the Christian main class?

Comment: I have to head off for a bit but I could try and explain further later. I would really suggest reading up on Initialization and Subclassing in Swift in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Since when are seminaries teaching programming?

Anyhow, I have a bone to pick with your assignment, and it's not about theology.

You are instructed to create `Baptist` and `Presbyterian` as subclasses of `Christian`. You are told to create Mary as a `Presbyterian`. You are then told to change Mary to a Reformed Baptist.

The problem is that once you have created Mary as a `Presbyterian`, there is no way to change her type without creating a new object:

```
var Mary = Presbyterian()  // Mary is forever a Presbyterian
```

You can't do this:

```
Mary = Baptist(ageOfAccountability: false) // Mary is a Presbyterian, remember?
```

You could only do this:

```
var Mary2 = Baptist(ageOfAccountability: false)  // this is a different Mary!
```

Mary2 is a new object. If you had set properties about Mary the Presbyterian, like her name, those would be lost when you recreated her. Not good!

It may be that your teacher wants you to change Mary the Presbyterian's mode of baptism:

```
Mary.modeOfBaptism = "Immersion"
```

But this makes no sense. Now you have a Presbyterian who believes in Immersion, which is clearly non-sensical and defeats the purpose of defining the Presbyterian class in the first place!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On the issue of the code not being correct, I agree. I have had problems with the code not being correct in my professor's playgrounds before.